# JPA+ Many-to-one relationship target entity is being saved in table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

My this question is follow up question of [JPA+one-to-many and many-to-one using join table or third table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406333/jpaone-to-many-and-many-to-one-using-join-table-or-third-table)

I am referencing the `Query` in `Response` entity. When I am creating an entry for `Response`. It also creates an entry in `mydb.tbl_query` table also. My requirement is that when I would insert `Response` entity it should insert the record in `mydb.tbl_response` and create an entry in `mydb.tbl_map_query_response` by referencing `query_id`.

```
    public class ResponseDAOImplTests extends BaseDAOImplTests {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("queryDAO")
        private QueryDAO queryDAO;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("responseDAO")
        private ResponseDAO responseDAO;

         /**
         * Query reference.
         */
        private Query query = null;

        /**
         * <p>
         * Adapter for earlier versions of JUnit.
         * </p>
         * 
         * @return a test suite.
         */
        public static junit.framework.Test suite() {
            return new JUnit4TestAdapter(ResponseDAOImplTests.class);
        }

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws QADAOException {
            user = accountDAO.getUser("query2@email.com");
            query = queryDAO.getQuery(2);

        }

        @Test
        public void createResponse() throws QADAOException {
            Response response = new Response();
            response.setQuery(query);
            response.setResponse("ResponseTest1");
            responseDAO.postResponse(response);

        }

    }
public class ResponseDAOImpl extends BasePersitenceDAO implements ResponseDAO {

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void postResponse(Response response) throws QADAOException {
        getEntityManager().persist(response);
        getEntityManager().flush();

    }
}

public abstract class BasePersitenceDAO {


    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    protected BasePersitenceDAO() {
        // Empty
    }
       protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

       public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
}

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.qa" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" />
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="basePersitenceDAO" abstract="true" class="com.qa.dao.impl.BasePersitenceDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="queryDAO" class="com.qa.dao.impl.QueryDAOImpl" parent="basePersitenceDAO" />
    <bean id="responseDAO" class="com.qa.dao.impl.ResponseDAOImpl" parent="basePersitenceDAO" />
</beans>
```

My issue is "it should not enter another record in `mydb.tbl_query`".

Comment: And your question is... ?

Comment: IN the other question, Response has a many-to-one to Query with cascade all set.  If you persist a Response, persist will get cascaded to the referenced Query object.  Same with merge and delete calls.  It shouldn't be able to insert a new Query object into the query table though if it already exists, so chances are you are creating a new Query entity.  You should find an existing one if you don't want a new record added to the Query table.

Comment: Even if I am finding the existing one it's also creating another record in Query table.

Comment: Show your code then.  How are you finding it and how is it creating a new one as the Query object should already have an ID value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cascade all forces every JPA operation to cascade over the referenced entity.  In this case, when you call persist on the new Response entity, you are effecively calling persist on the existing detached Query entity that you read in previously and just cached locally.  It is detached because it was read in a different context earlier.

Looking at the specification, persist is required to throw an exception when you call persist on a detached entity.  It just doesn't have to do it right away, and is instead allowing the insert to go through so that your database should throw an error - you didn't mention it, but I assume that is what is happening.  To avoid this, you cannot call persist on a detached entity.

You can easily fix this a number of ways
1) by not using cascade persist on your Response ->Query relationship.  Cascade all includes cascade persist, so you need to only add the cascading your model requires.  I strongly recommend you look at what cascading means and use it sparingly anyway.
2) look up the query in the same context you are persisting the Response.  Your Response DAO could easily take a Query ID and string value and create a Response object for you - doing the lookup for the Query using the Id.
3) use merge instead.  Merge will create the new Response, but will merge the detached Query instance into the managed copy it looks up.  This has risk though, as any changes made to the Query object will be merged and put into the database with the Response insert.  So your ResponseDAO picks up more than just Response changes.